# scrollviewer on image gives black background

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

When I set scrollviewer on image with white background and saved it to disc then my saved image has black color background.

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Height="500" Width="550" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ManipulationMode="All"  ManipulationDelta="scrollViewer_ManipulationDelta">
               <Image x:Name="targetSecond" Height="200" Width="200"  Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                     Source="">
                        <Image.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform/>
                        </Image.RenderTransform>
                    </Image>
                    <ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform/>
                    </ScrollViewer.RenderTransform>                   
               </ScrollViewer>
```

In scrollviewer I applied dragging of image also, it works fine.

How to save the image with a white background instead of black?

Comment: How are you saving the image to disk? Are you trying to render it? Using the built in `BitmapRenderer` or WinRTXamlToolkit's Composition engine? When you do, are you targeting the `ScrollViewer` or the `Image`?

Comment: I used RenderTargetBitmap and convert image to bitmap and then save it.And i am targeting image not scrollviewer, but due to scrollviewer width and height it shows black color, because i cropped my image and after that the remaining part shows black color.

Comment: When saving the rendertargetbitmap do you use the overload that automatically calculates the width and height? Try using the overload where you can set those manually and use the actual height and width of the image, and factor in the zoom factor of the scrollviewer and the render transforms of the image/scrollviewer.

Comment: I edited your question, assuming the actual background is white on screen. Please edit your question if it's inexact.